# CSS add a dot in a Line Chart in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

I'm trying to create a percentile chart, ie a chart with some lines corresponding to each percentile. Given a user input, I want to show their mark in the chart with a dot.

So basically, my question is: Is it possible to place a dot in a multiple line chart? If so, how do I do it?

```
var lineChart = new Chart(myChart2, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11'],
        datasets: [ {
            label: "50th",
            data: [20, 22, 28, 26, 25, 26],
            borderColor: '#166ab5',
            fill: false
        }, {
            label: "90th",
            data: [72, 74, 68, 75, 74, 78],
            borderColor: '#00FF00',
            fill: false
        }, {
            label: "10th",
            data: [2, 2, 5, 4, 6, 5],
            borderColor: '#FF0000',
            fill: false
        }]
    },
    
    options: {
        title: {
            text: "Percentile",
            display: true
        },
        legend: {
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
                  display: true,
                  scaleLabel: {
                      display: true,
                      labelString: ''
                  }
              }],
          yAxes: [{
                  display: true,
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true 
                      
                  }
              }]
        },
        annotation: {
            annotations: [{
                type: 'line',
                mode: 'horizontal',
                scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
                value: '26',
                borderColor: 'tomato',
                borderWidth: 1
            }],
            drawTime: "afterDraw" // (default)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What system are you using to draw the chart?

Comment: System? The page is in html/css/js

Comment: Sorry, I’d assumed Chart was from another library. What does Chart do?

Comment: it creates a line chart with 3 lines (corresponding to each one of the datasets)

Comment: @AHaworth is correct-- there is no `Chart` object or class in the JavaScript language or DOM API.  So the question is a fair one: what is in `Chart`?  Is it coming from a third party library?  Or have you written it yourself?  If the former, please mention this in the question and add a tag; if the latter, please share enough of your code to constitute a [mcve] so the community has sufficient details to help guide you in your inquiry.

Comment: oh okay right! It comes from another lib, this one: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0